# Pretty $lookup on collection - mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have two collection:

Competition

```
{
"_id": "326",
 signed_up": [
      {"_id": "00001","category": ["First"], "status": true}]
}
```

and Playing

```
{
  "_id": "6076e504db319b11c077d473",
   "competition_id": "326",
   "player": {"player_id": "00001","handicap": 6},  
   "totalScore": 6
}
```

I want to add playing --> totalScore on competition.signed_up array, based on player_id field:

```
{
 "_id": "326",
 signed_up": [
     {"_id": "00001","category": ["First"], "status": true, "totalScore": 6]
    }
```

I do not know how to do...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not telling you this is the optimal way, but it seems to work...

Let's start out with the data. I've added one player to the competition, just to make it a little easier to see that things works as expected:

```
db.competition.insertOne({
    "_id": "326",
    "signed_up": [{
        "_id": "00001",
        "category": ["First"],
        "status": true
    }, {
        "_id": "00002",
        "category": ["First"],
        "status": true
    }]
})

db.playing.insertMany([
    {
        "competition_id": "326",
        "player": {
            "playing_id": "00001"
        },
        "totalScore": 6 
    },
    {
        "competition_id": "326",
        "player": {
            "playing_id": "00002"
        },
        "totalScore": 2
    }
]);
```

Now for the aggregation...

```js
db.competition.aggregate([

// Even though the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use--lookup-with-an-array) states that unwinding is no longer necessary, 
// I'm not sure if that includes arrays of subdocuments or only arrays of primitives. So I've chosen to unwind anyway...
{ 
  $unwind: "$signed_up"
},
// =>  { "_id": "326", "signed_up": { "_id": "00001", ....} }

// now we have each player in it's own document and can easily lookup the score from playing collection
{ 
  $lookup: {
    from: 'playing',
    localField: 'signed_up._id',
    foreignField: 'player.playing_id',
    as: 'player'
  }
}, 
// => { "_id": "326", "signed_up": {...}, "player": [{ competition_id": "326"...}, ..]}

// now we have the matching competition documents as an array on each document. 
// But we know there will only be one match and don't really care for the array, 
// so we have to do some gymnastics to get the data we want where we want it
{
  $project: {
    "signed_up": {
      $let: {
        vars: {
          player: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$player", 0 ] }
        },
        in: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$signed_up", 
            { "totalScore": "$$player.totalScore" }
          ]    
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, 
// => { "_id": "326", "signed_up": { "_id": "00001", .... , "totalScore": 6 } }

// Now we're pretty much done, except that we need to group the documents back 
// into the original competition documents
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    signed_up: {
      $push: "$signed_up"
    }
  }
}
// => { "_id": "326", "signed_up": [ { "_id": "00001", ....}, {"_id": "00002", ...} ] }

// And that completes the pipeline. 
]);
```

I see that you have the id from the competition document also on the playing document, so I suspect that you need an additional check on the lookup to make sure you get the correct match. The way the code I have works, is that if you have more than one competition, you will get all the competitions for a player added to the playing array after the lookup.

If you take a look at the example [Specify Multiple Join Conditions with $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with--lookup) in the documentation, you see how you can change the $lookup stage to do a more precise match on the target documents by using a pipeline on the target collection. It also shows how you can include a projection in that pipeline to only return the data that you really want.

**Edit**

Take a look at the following alternative lookup step:

```js
{
  $lookup: { 
    from: 'playing',
    let: { playerid: "$signed_up._id", compid: "$_id" },
    pipeline: [
      { $match: {
          $expr: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: ["$player.playing_id","$$playerid" ] },
              { $eq: ["$competition_id", "$$compid" ] }
            ]
          }
        } 
      },  
     { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        "totalScore": 1  
      }
    } 
  ],
  as: 'player'
  }
}
```

This stores the players id and competition id from the current document into two variables. Then it uses those two variables in a pipeline run against the other collection. In addition to the $match to select the right player/competition document, it also includes a $project to get rid of the other fields on the playing documents. It will still return an array of one object, but it might save some bytes of memory usage...

Comment: Thanks @Vegar, but your solution not working correctly...Because the last stage $group obtain this: // => { "_id": "326", "signed_up": [ { "_id": "00001", ....totalScore : 6}, {"_id": "00002", ...totalScore : 6} ] } but totalScore on player 00002 it should be 2, not 6!

Comment: Yes, totalscore should be 2 for player 00002, and that's how the query works. I've just created a new blank database and pasted in the aggregation pipeline step by step just to be sure, and no matter which lookup alternative I use the result is the same. Player 1 gets score 6 and player 2 gets a score of 2. 
https://i.imgur.com/uBOcSVM.png